# HTML/Bootstrap Select Element

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How to set the select element looks like list? Something like this:

[image]

Sorry i'm just a newbie. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `size` attribute in `select` tag.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select size="7" class="form-control w-100">
  <option selected>John</option>
  <option>Paul</option>
  <option>Ringo</option>
  <option>George</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "multiple" feature in select element:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select multiple class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a example**

`Bootstrap v3.7`
For `<select>` controls with the `multiple` attribute, multiple options are shown by default.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<select multiple class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

you can learn https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms

```
Bootstrap (Currently v4.0.0-beta)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

You can learn it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls